# Can someone explain the prop.table function in laymans terms?

Tags: r

I am a university student learning R and am struggling to understand the literature around what `prop.table` is and how to use it.

I have been directed to use it for a table representing stakeholders’ responses to a question with strongly agree, agree, nuetral, disagree and strongly disagree, however, we have never been shown this function.

Would really appreciate someone explaining it to me in layman terms!

I would like to be able to format my data into a table that is legible, in comparison to the script itself.

Answer (score 4):

First, as @jay.sf points out, `prop.table()` has been renamed [`proportions()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/proportions.html) as of R 4.0.0 (though `prop.table()` is retained as an alias for backwards compatibility).

In the simplest case, given a numeric vector, `proportions()` tells you what percentage of the total each number is. For example,

```r
vec <- c(1, 1, 2)
proportions(vec)
# 0.25 0.25 0.50

## is equivalent to 
vec / sum(vec)
# 0.25 0.25 0.50
```

Given a matrix or 2-way table, it returns each number as a proportion of the row sum (if `margin = 1`), the column sum (if `margin = 2`), or the grand sum (if `margin` is omitted):

```r
(m <- matrix(1:4, nrow = 2))
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    3
# [2,]    2    4

proportions(m, 1)
#           [,1]      [,2]
# [1,] 0.2500000 0.7500000
# [2,] 0.3333333 0.6666667

proportions(m, 2)
#           [,1]      [,2]
# [1,] 0.3333333 0.4285714
# [2,] 0.6666667 0.5714286

proportions(m)
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]  0.1  0.3
# [2,]  0.2  0.4
```

If your dimensions are named, you can pass the dimension name to `margin`:

```r
(counts <- xtabs(Freq ~ Hair + Eye, data = HairEyeColor))
#         Eye
# Hair    Brown Blue Hazel Green
#   Black    68   20    15     5
#   Brown   119   84    54    29
#   Red      26   17    14    14
#   Blond     7   94    10    16

## eye color as % of hair color
proportions(counts, "Hair")
#         Eye
# Hair         Brown       Blue      Hazel      Green
#   Black 0.62962963 0.18518519 0.13888889 0.04629630
#   Brown 0.41608392 0.29370629 0.18881119 0.10139860
#   Red   0.36619718 0.23943662 0.19718310 0.19718310
#   Blond 0.05511811 0.74015748 0.07874016 0.12598425
## e.g., among those with black hair, 62.9% have brown eyes
```

Finally, `proportions()` can be used with higher dimensional arrays, too:

```r
(counts_3way <- xtabs(Freq ~ Hair + Eye + Sex, data = HairEyeColor))
# , , Sex = Male
# 
#         Eye
# Hair    Brown Blue Hazel Green
#   Black    32   11    10     3
#   Brown    53   50    25    15
#   Red      10   10     7     7
#   Blond     3   30     5     8
# 
# , , Sex = Female
# 
#         Eye
# Hair    Brown Blue Hazel Green
#   Black    36    9     5     2
#   Brown    66   34    29    14
#   Red      16    7     7     7
#   Blond     4   64     5     8

## eye color as % of hair color within each sex
proportions(counts_3way, c("Hair", "Sex"))
# , , Sex = Male
# 
#        Eye
# Hair         Brown       Blue      Hazel      Green
#   Black 0.57142857 0.19642857 0.17857143 0.05357143
#   Brown 0.37062937 0.34965035 0.17482517 0.10489510
#   Red   0.29411765 0.29411765 0.20588235 0.20588235
#   Blond 0.06521739 0.65217391 0.10869565 0.17391304
# 
# , , Sex = Female
# 
#        Eye
# Hair         Brown       Blue      Hazel      Green
#   Black 0.69230769 0.17307692 0.09615385 0.03846154
#   Brown 0.46153846 0.23776224 0.20279720 0.09790210
#   Red   0.43243243 0.18918919 0.18918919 0.18918919
#   Blond 0.04938272 0.79012346 0.06172840 0.09876543
## e.g., among males with black hair, 57.1% have brown eyes
```